# How can I import a database with MySQL from terminal?

Tags: mysql, import

How can I import a database with mysql from terminal?

I cannot find the exact syntax.

Answer (score 880, accepted):

Assuming you're on a Linux or Windows console:

Prompt for password:

```
mysql -u <username> -p <databasename> < <filename.sql>
```

Enter password directly (not secure):

```
mysql -u <username> -p<PlainPassword> <databasename> < <filename.sql>
```

Example:

```
mysql -u root -p wp_users < wp_users.sql

mysql -u root -pPassword123 wp_users < wp_users.sql
```

See also:

[4.5.1.5. Executing SQL Statements from a Text File](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-batch-commands.html)

---

**Note**: If you are on windows then you will have to `cd` (change directory)  to your MySQL/bin directory inside the CMD before executing the command.

Comment: +1 except for you shouldn't pass your password as CLI parameter. Rather just specify -p option and enter it manually after prompt.

Comment: There is no space between -p and the password if you want to enter it by shell.

Comment: mysql -u username -h hostname -ppassword databasename < filename.sql for remote host from the terminal

Comment: if you are already inside mysql command prompt (mysql>), then simply type source full_path_of_file (note: select database by command USE DATABASE_NAME before import).

Comment: @Pekka웃, If we use `source`, we can see the informational messages (*"rows affected"*) and error messages. But using your solution, How do we see the messages using `< filename.sql` ?

Comment: Any ideas why the one liner `mysql -u username -p databasename < filename.sql`is painly slow compared to `source filename.sql`? (using XAMPP on Windows)

Comment: too much mambo, jambo. All hail source.

Comment: add full path to your file /var/www/... whatever, or cd into it, otherwise it won't be found.

Comment: how to verbose because my sql doesnt on import , but the process has alr done .

Answer (score 167):

Preferable way for windows:

1. Open the console and start the interactive MySQL mode
2. `use <name_of_your_database>;`
3. `source <path_of_your_.sql>`

Comment: why don't we need a ; after file name?

Comment: @NabeelKhan *Most* SQL statements require a `;` at the end of the statement, but there are a few exceptions, including `USE` and `SOURCE`.

Comment: I wonder if this performs faster than piping the file in (like in the accepted answer). My suspicion is *yes*.

Comment: This is so much faster than importing through HeidiSQL...3GB in 20 minutes!

Comment: there's no need to use "use <name_of_your_database>", right?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-batch-commands.html

Comment: @Martian2049, When I omited `USE <database>`, it didn't import the database (Mysql version 14.14)

Comment: @MartianMartian You need to tell the `mysql` utility which database to use (=import into). Either you specify the database name on the command line when running `mysql -u <user> -p <database>`, or in the console with the `USE <database>` command. If you do neither, MySQL doesn't know which DB to target.

Answer (score 38):

`mysql -u <USERNAME> -p <DB NAME> < <dump file path>`

`-u` - for Username

`-p` - to prompt the Password

**Eg.** `mysql -u root -p mydb < /home/db_backup.sql`

You can also provide password preceded by -p but for the security reasons it is not suggestible. The password will appear on the command itself rather masked.

Comment: This is the answer i am looking for. " < " this is the sign which I left.

Comment: If mydb does not exists then how to create it dynamically when we fire mysqldump command?

Answer (score 19):

Directly from var/www/html

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < /path/to/file.sql
```

From within mysql:

```
mysql> use db_name;
mysql> source backup-file.sql
```

Answer (score 14):

Open Terminal Then

```
 mysql -u root -p

 eg:- mysql -u shabeer -p
```

After That Create a Database

```
 mysql> create database "Name";

 eg:- create database INVESTOR;
```

Then Select That New Database "INVESTOR"

```
 mysql> USE INVESTOR;
```

Select the path of sql file from machine

```
 mysql> source /home/shabeer/Desktop/new_file.sql;
```

Then press enter and wait for some times if it's all executed then

```
 mysql> exit
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Below command is working on ubuntu 16.04, I am not sure it is working or not other Linux platforms.

Export SQL file:

```
$ mysqldump -u [user_name] -p [database_name] > [database_name.sql]
```

> Example :  mysqldump -u root -p max_development > max_development.sql

**Import SQL file:**

```
$ mysql -u[user_name] -p [database_name] < [file_name.sql]
```

> Example: mysqldump -u root -p max_production < max_development.sql

**Note SQL file should exist same directory**

Comment: I think your Import command is wrong.  Importing is done with "mysql" cmd.  "mysqldump" is for export.

Answer (score 7):

From Terminal:

```
mysql -uroot -p --default-character-set=utf8 database_name </database_path/database.sql
```

Answer (score 7):

in the terminal type

```
mysql -uroot -p1234; use databasename; source /path/filename.sql
```

Comment: This allowed to see the import log

Answer (score 6):

I usually use this command to load my SQL data when divided in files with names : 000-tableA.sql, 001-tableB.sql, 002-tableC.sql.

```
for anyvar in *.sql; do <path to your bin>/mysql -u<username> -p<password>  <database name> < $anyvar; done
```

Works well on OSX shell.

Answer (score 5):

[image: How to load from command line]

Explanation:

1. First create a database or use an existing database. In my case, I am using an existing database
2. Load the database by giving `<name of database> = ClassicModels` in my case and using the operator `<` give the path to the `database = sakila-data.sql`
3. By running show tables, I get the list of tables as you can see.

Note : In my case I got an *error 1062*, because I am trying to load the same thing again.

Answer (score 5):

```
mysql -u username -ppassword dbname < /path/file-name.sql
```

example

```
mysql -u root -proot product < /home/myPC/Downloads/tbl_product.sql
```

Use this from terminal

Answer (score 5):

After struggling for sometime I found the information in https://tommcfarlin.com/importing-a-large-database/

1. Connect to Mysql (let's use root for both username and password):

   ```
   mysql -uroot -proot
   ```
2. Connect to the database (let's say it is called emptyDatabase (your should get a confirmation message):

   ```
   connect emptyDatabase
   ```

3 Import the source code, lets say the file is called mySource.sql and it is in a folder called mySoureDb under the profile of a user called myUser:

```
source /Users/myUser/mySourceDB/mySource.sql
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Open the MySQL Command Line Client and type in your password
2. Change to the database you want to use for importing the .sql file data into. Do this by typing:

   ```
   USE your_database_name
   ```
3. Now locate the .sql file you want to execute.
   If the file is located in the main local C: drive directory and the .sql script file name is `currentSqlTable.sql`, you would type the following:

   ```
   \. C:\currentSqlTable.sql
   ```

   and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute the SQL script file.

Comment: What is Figure 1/2/3?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using *sakila-db* from mysql website,
It's very easy on the Linux platform just follow the below-mentioned steps, After downloading the zip file of *sakila-db*, extract it. Now you will have two files, one is ***sakila-schema.sql* and the other one is *sakila-data.sql***.

---

1. Open terminal
2. Enter command ***mysql -u root -p < sakila-schema.sql***
3. Enter command ***mysql -u root -p < sakila-data.sql***
4. Now enter command ***mysql -u root -p*** and enter your password, now you have entered into mysql system with *default* database.
5. To use sakila database, use this command ***use sakila;***
6. To see tables in sakila-db, use  ***show tables*** command

---

Please take care that *extracted files are present in home directory*.

Answer (score 3):

First connect to mysql via command line

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Enter MySQL PW

Select target DB name

```
use <db_name>
```

Select your db file for import

```
SET autocommit=0; source /root/<db_file>;

commit;
```

This should do it. (thanks for clearing)
This will work even 10GB DB can be imported successfully this way. :)

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu/Linux users,
Extract the SQL file and paste it somewhere

e.g you pasted on desktop

1. open the terminal
2. go to your database and create a database name
3. Create database db_name;
4. Exit `Mysql` from your terminal
5. cd DESKTOP
6. `mysql -u root -p db_name <  /cd/to/mysql.sql`
7. Enter the password:....

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu, from **MySQL monitor**, you have already used this syntax:

`mysql> use <dbname>`
-> The USE statement tells MySQL to use `dbname` as the default database for subsequent statements

```
mysql> source <file-path>
```

**for example**:

```
mysql> use phonebook;

mysql> source /tmp/phonebook.sql;
```

**Important**: make sure the sql file is in a directory that mysql **can access** to like /tmp

Answer (score 2):

If you want to import a database from a SQL dump which might have "use" statements in it, I recommend to use the "-o" option as a safeguard to not accidentially import to a wrong database.

```
   •   --one-database, -o

       Ignore statements except those those that occur while the default
       database is the one named on the command line. This filtering is
       limited, and based only on USE statements. This is useful for
       skipping updates to other databases in the binary log.
```

Full command:

```
mysql -u <username> -p -o <databasename> < <filename.sql>
```

Answer (score 1):

Before running the commands on the terminal you have to make sure that you have MySQL installed on your terminal.

You can use the following command to install it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Refrence [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-14-04).

After that you can use the following commands to import a database:

```
mysql -u <username> -p <databasename> < <filename.sql>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to import a database in your MYSQL from the terminal is done by the below-mentioned process -

```
mysql -u root -p root database_name < path to your .sql file
```

What I'm doing above is:

1. Entering to mysql with my username and password (here it is `root` & `root`)
2. After entering the password I'm giving the name of database where I want to import my .sql file. **Please make sure the database already exists in your MYSQL**
3. The database name is followed by `<` and then path to your .sql file. For example, if my file is stored in Desktop, the path will be `/home/Desktop/db.sql`

That's it. Once you've done all this, press enter and wait for your .sql file to get uploaded to the respective database

Answer (score 0):

There has to be no space between -p and password

```
mysql -u [dbusername] -p[dbpassword] [databasename] < /home/serverusername/public_html/restore_db/database_file.sql
```

I always use it, it works perfectly. Thanks to ask this question. Have a great day. Njoy :)

Comment: we can also set this settings in cron job (schedule task) on shared, dedicated and cloud servers to reset or import database time to time automatically.