# How do I open an sql database that I downloaded using the terminal?

Tags: sql, database, import, load, terminal

[How can I import a database with MySQL from terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546778/how-can-i-import-a-database-with-mysql-from-terminal)
the syntax from this thread

```
mysql -u username -ppassword databasename < filename.sql
```

my input for the file (lahman591) i placed on my root for simplicity sake

```
mysql> mysql -u root -p lahman591 <c:\lahman591.sql
```

i get an Error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) You have an error in your sql syntax.
```

Comment: You can also do this from the `mysql>` prompt via `mysql> source filename.sql`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it from your normal shell (the command is calling the `mysql` bin), not mysql shell.

Comment: I love when an answer can be as short as this and still be the right answer. +1