# Importing a SQL db into mysql using the terminal

Tags: mysql, sql, import, terminal

I'm struggling to do this.

I have created a new database in the terminal called "somedb" using

```
CREATE DATABASE somedb
```

On my desktop I have the SQL dump downloaded from phpMyadmin: somedb.sql

I have tried:

```
somedb < /Users/myname/Desktop/somedb.sql
```

Result: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax

```
mysql -u myname -p -h localhost somedb </Users/myname/Desktop/somedb.sql
```

Result: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

I'm new to SQL (The purpose of importing this db is for a text book exercise)

I have granted myself all privileges and there is no password.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the top of the SQL dump file:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.2
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Jun 18, 2013 at 02:22 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.31-30.3
-- PHP Version: 5.2.17

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `somedb`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `somedb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
USE `somedb`;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `actions`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `actions` (
  `action_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `action` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  `qualifiers` text NOT NULL,
  `response` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  `response_vars` text NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`action_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Stores user defined actions triggered by certain events' AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found an SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546778/how-can-i-import-a-database-with-mysql-from-terminal).

I used "source" like so:

```
SOURCE /Users/myname/Desktop/somedb.sql;
```

That worked. Great but the internet seemed to want me to use the method like so:

```
mysql -u username -p password databasename < filename.sql
```

I may post another question on when to use that second method but in the meantime I just used source from a SQL dump file

Comment: What the internet wants the internet gets! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Using MAMP Pro, created "uploads" dir in MAMP and put my SQL file in there called "file.sql". Ran the query below in terminal and worked for me.

Make sure to replace brackets and and user info with no spaces after "-u" or "-p"

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u<username> -p<root> <db_name> < /Applications/MAMP/uploads/file.sql
```

Comment: perfect answer!!! no need to create upload folder! we may drag located files to terminal as well!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way..

Go to the mysql prompt and then type the following.

```
mysql> \. <path> /filename.sql
```

Note the gap between . and the path of the sql file.Hope this works.

Answer (score 1):

Type this on terminal

```
sudo mysql -p database_name < folder/database_dump_file.sql
```

it will then ask you for the mysql password

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -uUser -p --default-character-set=utf8 databasename < /<path to .sql>
```

(-p) will ask for password