# mysqldump not importing all databases

Tags: database, import, mysql

I need to import a very large backup pf my database.

I'm using this command for importing all databases:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases < localhost.sql
```

It works, but only 5 db of 6 were imported.

The file has 700'000 lines so is very difficoult select only the last db i care about.

Any advices? Thank you!

EDIT:

Using

```
mysqldump -u root -p joomla < localhost.sql
```

got an error

```
    '[root@tp lota]# mysqldump -u root -p joomla < localhost.sql
Enter password: 
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.1.69, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: joomla
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.1.69

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database 'joomla' when selecting the database'
```

EDIT #2: the problem was database information_schema inside the dump. After deleting it all went ok. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: What's the problem? Do you want to have 6th database to be dumped as well or you want to check if it's dump is present in the dump file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546778/how-can-i-import-a-database-with-mysql-from-terminal

Comment: the databse exist, i want to import only the 6th

Comment: Dare I say that there are Joomla extensions that do these things with a few clicks (like Akeeba Backup Core), but I guess you want to customize it somehow.

Comment: this is a very old name, the db has name joomla but inside there is everything but no joomla :D

Comment: @lexolas You got me there.

Answer (score 5):

Rather use mysql (not mysqldump) to import the data:

```
mysql -u root -p < localhost.sql
```

mysqldump is for exporting data. Also, you may need to create the (empty) database before importing.

Comment: mysqldump -u root -p joomla > localhost.sql is the correct usage for exporting data

Answer (score 3):

Open Terminal and enter below commands

```
 mysql -u root -p

eg:- mysql -u abcd -p
```

Check databases that are present

```
mysql> show databases;
```

Create a Database if not created before

```
 mysql> create database "Name";

 eg:- create database ABCD;
```

Then Select That New Database "ABCD"

```
 mysql> USE ABCD;
```

Select the path of SQL file from the machine

```
 mysql> source /home/Desktop/new_file.sql;
```

Then press enter and wait for some times if it's all executed then

```
 mysql> exit
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, though its not the smartest solutions available in most cases but it worked for me when newer version of mysql was throwing an error on dump, setting sql_mode to NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER was the issue so restoring data from such files was failing simple dump commands like mysql -u USER -p DB < dump.sql
But thankfully your steps worked.

Comment: [Adnan Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2086124/adnan-ali) Thanks, Yeah in most of the cases it worked better than other solutions.