# Moving WordPress site to IIS 7.5

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, iis

I currently have a WordPress site hosted on Site5 (apache/linux) and I would like to move it to my Virtual Dedicated Server running Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 7.5.

I have gone ahead and made a full backup of my database and WordPress files on Site5.

And on the Windows Server, I have MySQL and PHP installed. The problem is there is no PhpMyAdmin on my Windows Server and I can't seem to install it. If I had that, then I think I'd know what to do.

Right now, I have no idea how I can port my MySQL backup to the MySQL instance on my Windows Server. I think I might be OK after that point, I think after that it might be a case of editing the `wp-config.php` file.

Can someone please help me get my backup file imported into MySQL on my Windows Server machine?

I have tried the following (whilst inside `mysql>`)

```
mydb < mybackupfile.sql;
```

But that just gives me an error saying there is something wrong with my syntax!

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I import a database with mysql from terminal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546778/how-can-i-import-a-database-with-mysql-from-terminal)

Comment: I tried that command, but I get an error :( It says "you have an error in your sql syntax"

Comment: That isn't SQL, it's a command. Don't run it from mysql, just run it from command line.