# MySQL database load to server

Tags: mysql, terminal

In order to load databases to mysql using terminal, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546778/how-can-i-import-a-database-with-mysql-from-terminal), the sql file must be already in the server? Or I can upload from my local pc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you have mysql installed in your local machine:** then you can at once run the import command from local machine's command line

```
mysql -hmy_server -umy_user -p database_name < full/path/to/file.sql
```

or you can just go to the directory where your sql file exists and run

```
mysql -hmy_server -umy_user -p database_name < file.sql
```

(password will be required after hitting Enter). This way the file will be imported into the remote database from your local computer.

**No mysql is installed in your local machine:** in this case you have to manually upload the file into the server with some ftp client and then connect remotely(e.g. by [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)) and run similar command

```
mysql -umy_user -p database_name < path/to/sql/file.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can SCP or SFTP it to the server, but that command expects a file on the machine. In fact, that particular command expects it to be in the same directory that you are in.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file contains SQL statements it can go anywhere. What is important is that the MySQL client you use to read the file can access the database server - usually on port 3306 for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

On the server, unless your local directory is accessible via network to the server (i.e. network share on another machine which is mapped to some address on your server - convoluted but essentially possible).

Basically, just upload the file to the server and run the command locally there.

Answer (score 0):

NO, the SQL file or SQL script file generally can be present in your machine. When you execute the command, said sql script gets executed against the database.

```
mysql -u user -p -h servername DB < [Full Path]/test.sql
```