# how to restore mysql.dump database backup file

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Hi i have a backup file from a database.

The file name is mysql.dump

I tried to restore it using phpmyadmin but i got wrong file type error

1.Is it a true mysql backup file or not?

2.How to restore it?

My question is not possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546778) because:

1.I never asked for restore using terminal and will never ask.

2.My question wasn't about ways of importing a .sql file it was about importing an unknown backup file type.

Comment: open mysql.dump in a text editor to see if it contains sql.  you can also import mysql data from the shell http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546778/how-can-i-import-a-database-with-mysql-from-terminal

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After i changed the file type from .dump to .sql my database restored with no error