# emoji display as ? in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, emoji

Emoji are stored as ? in my database (when i'm visualizing them using phpMyAdmin), however when i retrieve them using a simple request (from php) i get the real value.

**line on database (using phpMyAdmin)**
[image]

**Request from php**

```
$query = "SELECT id,com
          FROM coms_table
          WHERE id = 627";
```

**Result**

```
id     com  
627    \ud83d\ude0e
```

---

Using this command

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
```

i get this :
   [image]

my.cnf file :

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysqld]
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
innodb_file_per_table=1
performance-schema=0
innodb_buffer_pool_size=134217728
max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit=10000
local-infile=0
character-set-client-handshake = TRUE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

To summary, the issue only occurs when i'm connecting to database using phpMyAdmin. Worst, when i try to import database using phpMyAdmin, all question marks are replaced by true "?", and datas are definitively lost.

**EDIT 1**
phpMyAdmin>Variables
[image]
Session values(utf8) are different to expected values(utf8mb4)

Comment: What version of phpMyAdmin are you running? It sounds like it doesn't support the character encoding you're using.

Comment: @RyanLaBarre i 'm running the version 4.0.10.14 of phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's appear that's a phpMyAdmin bug (corrected at version 4.6.4).
When you use phpMyAdmin to connect to your database, the session's variables like `character_set_client` and `character_set_results` aren't initialized with the default values.
See this [commit](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/fb30c148f22f3e1534cb216a5994660b09c70795).

If you have this bug and want import/export your database, don't use phpMyAdmin.
As a workaround, perform the import action using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4546797), and the export action using the documentation at [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need `character_set_client, _connection, and _results` to all be utf8mb4.  The rest do not matter.

The *single* question mark probably means that the data was lost as it was inserted.  (4 question marks for 1 emoji would mean a different problem.)

Comment: I've tried to set `character_set_client` and `character_set_results` on **utf8mb4** editing my.cnf file (/etc/my.cnf) but it has no effect

Comment: I've edited my post, you can see that `character_set_client ` and `character_set_results ` values are equal to **utf8mb4**. However Session Values are different. Any idea? (I've already restart mysql and restart the server)

Comment: I am unclear on how, or even _if_, those settings make it through to the session.  When connecting, one should establish the character set that the client is using.  This is done in different ways by different clients.  Some listed [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#other_computer_languages).