# VBulletin mysql database, Old db with less threads but I have a newer post table

Tags: php, mysql, vbulletin

Long story short, one of my servers was rooted all I have is a database that's 5 months old and the tables for user and post that are 2 months old.

I'm trying to re add 2000+ posts to the thread table by inserting the `threadid`, `title`, `forumid` and `open` rows manually. But that is going to take forever.

My knowledge on MySQL is limited but not non-existent. Please help!

Comment: Can you not just *import* the back-up in the database? Inside the PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: I did that and then imported the newer user and post tables. The issue is the thread table doesn't have the data from the post table. So if i manually inserted the threadid from the post table through phpmyadmin i would still have to copy over the title row from the post table to actually get the thread to show up on the forums. Basically the thread table is older than the post table.

Comment: Oh right, so you  have two sql files and you want to merge the data together and then import it?

Comment: No basically in my thread table there are say 3200 threads on the forum in my new post table there are 5200 posts(because it's newer than the thread table). The threads table gets data like the title and content of the from the post table but if those threadids don't exist in the thread table those posts wont show up on the forums.

Currently i'm just adding the missing row like this: 

insert into thread (threadid) values (5224), (5223), (5222), (5221), (5220), (5219), (5218), (5217), (5216), (5215);

Comment: And i just change the values lower each time i run the query. However i still need to get the title column from the post table and i've been doing that manually by copying and pasting it over.

Comment: Punctuation, splitting paragraphs and backquotes in rows

Comment: it seems you need to know how to import data to your database, this might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/4546797/1197775