# Laravel 5. Error "VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008]" when run "composer dump-autoload"

Tags: database, laravel-5, laravel-seeding

I get an error "Class does not exist" when trying to populate my DB by executing
"php artisan seed:db".

**UserMoviesSeeder.php** in the folder **database/seeds** has the following content:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Project;
use App\UserMovie;
use App\User;

class UserMoviesSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
      $this->call(ProjectsTableSeeder::class);
    }
}

class ProjectsTableSeeder extends Seeder {

   public function run()
   {
       DB::table('user_movies')->delete();
       DB::disableQueryLog();

       UserMovie::create([
           'user_id' => 1734805,
           'tmdb_id' => 100,
           'ratio' => 4
       ]);

       UserMovie::create([
           'user_id' => 716091,
           'tmdb_id' => 100,
           'ratio' => 4
       ]);

       // ... and so on
   }
}
```

I run the command:

```
php artisan db:seed --class=UserMoviesSeeder
```

And I get an error:

```
In Container.php line 752:
Class UserMoviesSeeder does not exist
```

I tried the following:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

It returns:

```
VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] ������������ ������ ��� ��������� �������.

VirtualAlloc() failed: [0x00000008] ������������ ������ ��� ��������� �������.
```

If I rename both, the file and the class to standard name "DatabaseSeeder" and run the command:

```
php artisan db:seed
```

Then I have an error:

```
 Out of memory (allocated 547356672) (tried to allocate 1073741824 bytes)
```

I assume that 547356672 is the size of my seeder file (it is about 5.5Gb).
But why it tries to allocate twice more 1073741824 ?
I have only 8Gb of RAM, so it can't allocate 10Gb.
Previously I had 10Gb seeder in this folder, but now I have just one seeder file of 5.5Gb there.

Comment: what is the file size of your seeder?

Comment: seeder is about 5.5Gb

Comment: the file is too large, try to import through command or import it batch by batch

Comment: "batch by batch" will take a huge amount of time, but what do you mean by "import through command"?

Comment: insert batch by batch (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql), insert through command (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546778/how-can-i-import-a-database-with-mysql-from-terminal)