# Memory size error when importing sql.zip file into phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, server, phpmyadmin

I'm having issues importing a sql.zip file into phpmyadmin. When I try to import the file I get the following error: 

 **Fatal error**:

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>   132382880 bytes) in **/usr/share/phpmyadmin/export.php** on line
>   **310**

I've gone into the config file and the `memory_limit is set to -1` (would it be better to set the limit?) and when I navigate into the `export.php` file I can't find a reason for the error. As far as I know the `export.php` file is still default, no one has edited the file. 
[Here's an image of the line (cursor marking line 310)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0foT.png)

I've been beating my head against this for ages, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is either something in the sql.zip file that is causing the problem or the zip file is exceeding the file size limit.

Comment: Why import the DB via PHP? Just do it via the mysql interface, it is very straight forward

Comment: What about upload_max_filesize, post_max_size, max_execution_time and max_input_time?

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4546797/5458355.
With a terminal, having mysql in your global path, try:

```
mysql -u <username> -p <databasename> < <filename.sql>
```

Is faster to import the db from terminal and you must do it if the file is too big... check also your Apache limits for file upload and memory limit.