# ERROR 1064 (42000): MySql Database Setup/Recovery Issue from Backupon Mac

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, database-administration

I am trying to restore a new MySql database instance from some .backup files.

I have navigated to the folder with the backup files and logged into the mysql and on the propt.

But the following command is not working for me:

```
  CREATE DATABASE abcDb;
```

Then to restore from .backup

```
  mysql -u root -p abcDb < abcDb.backup
```

I tried the following too:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p abcDb < /Applications/Development/capify/DB/db_dump/abcDb.backup
```

I am getting error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'mysql -u root -p abcDb < abcDb.backup' at line 1
>
> DB Server version: 8.0.21 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Please, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Out of curiosity: what does that backup file contain? A usual SQL dump?

Comment: Hello thanks for responding.Yes, it contains an sql dump. But, I am not sure if that is a valid backup file extension or i need to rename it to .sql.

Comment: Why not check what that file contains? Also, how do you try to restore that backup? Are you running that from the MySQL shell?

Comment: It contains some create table and populates the tables as well statements ....

Comment: And how exactly do you run `mysql -u root -p abcDb < abcDb.backup` - within the MySQL shell, or in some kind of Bash?

Comment: I am running it directly on the mysql terminal after logging in as: % /usr/local/mysql/bin/./sql -u root -p

Comment: That's not possible - either run the import on the shell (without logging in to MySQL first!), or use `SOURCE`.  More information can be found on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546778/how-can-i-import-a-database-with-mysql-from-terminal

Comment: What! Thanks for that ... I will look at the reference. Please, is xxx.backup a valid file name to import from or do i need to rename to xxx.sql?

Comment: As far as I know, it's completely irrelevant how you name that file

Comment: Thanks a million Nico, you are a super star. The source option is working : use <name_of_your_database>; source <path_of_your_.sql>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a million Nico, you are a super star.
The source option works :

```
create <name_of_your_database>; 

use <name_of_your_database>; 

source <path_of_your_.sql>
```